# How to add Scopes in Authentication and Authorization Configuration

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, azure-web-app-service

Am trying to configure Azure Authen/Authr for Azure App Service. While configuring this on Azure portal, i see the scopes have been listed for Microsoft and Facebook Configuration but not for Google. 
While authenticating via google am getting invalid request scope is required.

How to add Scopes to Google configuration on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step by step instruction in c[onfigure your App Service application to use Google login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-google).